# How to manage unique Ids with Hibernate and Flyway?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, flyway, uniqueidentifier

Here is a snippet of my entity class

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
```

When using (Spring Boot + Hibernate) Spring Boot setups schema automatically including sequences like one below

```
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
```

But I am using Flyway 5.0.7 to setup my schema. And in this case I get the error below, which means sequence is not getting created.

```
Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement
```

I was able to fix this by creating sequence using flyway script like below

```
create sequence HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE start with 1001;
```

But now this sequence is used to generate Ids for all entities which I do not want. I want each entity to have its separate sequence.

Is it possible to create sequences using Hibernate when using Flyway? Otherwise it is not practical to manually create sequences for all entities which can be in hundreds.

Any alternative approach to handle this?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be practical? If you have hundreds of entities, you have hundreds of classes to create, hundreded of tables, constraints, indices, etc. to create using Flyway, and probably a huge code base to maintain. Having one trivial line of SQL to create a sequence for each entty should be the least of your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

Flyway is a DB migration tool, and it does not know of any DDL/DML changes unless you tell it so (via new scripts in the locations property).

If Hibernate handles some of these changes (the sequences in your case) Flyway won't know about it and will use whatever sequence it already has knowledge about.

The normal thing to do is letting Flyway know of your changes, which includes a new sequence for a new entity for instance, just like you would do for the schema itself of your entity. My personal advice is to manage all your schema changes in one place, so if you are using Flyway, then let it be in charge of all of it.